# homomorphic maps between the rings $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: ring-theory

I wanted to find all the homomorphisms 
$\theta : \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} \ \rightarrow \ \mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z} $.

---

I thought that it would be enough to describe the map by $1 \mapsto a$ for some $a$, since $1$ generates the ring $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. The order of $\theta(1)$ has to devide $12$. That means that its order must belong to $\{0,2,3,4,6,12\}$.

- For $ord(a) = 2$, we can only choose $a=21$
- If $ord(a) = 3$, we can choose $a=14,28$
- The number $4$ does not divide $42$.
- For $ord(a)=6$ we have $7,35$
- And $12$ does not divide $42$

Those numbers are all the possible values for $a$.

---

*Is this the right way to find those maps, or is there something I forgot?*

Comment: Looks great. Right way.

Comment: Your procedure looks good. Just a very small issue -- you want $1$ instead of $0$ your lists of possible orders.  This gives a (trivial) possibility for a map with $\theta(1)$ of order $1$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ring homomorphism $\theta:\Bbb Z/(12\Bbb Z)\to \Bbb Z/(42\Bbb Z)$ because $42$ not divide $12$ ,indeed ; if $\theta $ is such homomorphism, since $\theta(1)=1$, we have $12=12\theta(1)=\theta(12)=0 \mod [42]$, $i.e$ $42$ divide $12$.

Comment: Who said the homomorphism needs to be surjective?

Comment: I've never used the surjectivity!

Comment: Do ring homomorphisms have to preserve the identity $1$ ?

Comment: See the definition of [rings homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism)

Comment: @Hamou what matters is the way that the OP defines a ring homomorphism. From what they've written, it seems that they do not require $1$ to be preserved (however, you're right that they should make this explicit). Sometimes a ring homomorphism is defined to be any map preserving operations, and what you call a homomorphism of rings is called a *homomorphism of rings with $1$*.